# Vue+Vuetify+Nuxt - Render a list of components in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**My situation**

I've got a bunch of custom components that I want to put into tabs

```
import UserTable from '...'
import User from '...'
.
.
components: { 
  UserTable, 
  User 
}

data () { 
  return { 
    listComponents: [ UserTable, User] 
  }
}
```

**What I'd like to do**

Something like the following

```
<v-tab-item v-for="i in listComponents">
  <slots item:i> // or similar
</v-tab-item>
```

to iterate imported components in the `html` part

**The purpose**

To be able to skip copy pasting

```
<v-tab-item>
  <component_number_1>
</v-tab-item>
```

repeatedly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Dynamic Components -
[Docs Vue@2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)
[Docs Vue@3](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

You list should contain the Names of the component in string format like so:

```
components: { 
  UserTable, 
  User 
},
data () { 
  return { 
    listComponents: ['UserTable', 'User']
  }
}
```

```
<v-tab-item v-for="component in listComponents">
  <component v-bind:is="component"></component>
</v-tab-item>
```

My personal opinion: this looks like overkill unless you have more than 5 components that need to be displayed like this, as you lose some visibility in the template of what is used.